# Why is there an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PinsController#show for a link on my pin?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a link on my footer. It works on every page except when you click it while viewing a pin, it returns the following Error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PinsController#show
Extracted source (around line #61):

```
Couldn't find Pin with 'id'=terms
private
    def set_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
```

Why does it encounter this bug only when someone clicks to try to view the link on the footer while on the pin page?

Here are more relevant details:

pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :bid]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
@pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
end

def bid
 Bid.where(user_id: current_user.id, pin_id: @pin.id).each do |bid|
  bid.cancel!
end

bid = Bid.new
bid.user = current_user
bid.pin = @pin
bid.price = params[:price].to_f
bid.quantity = params[:quantity] ? params[:quantity].to_i : 1
bid.save
render json: {
    success: true
}
   end

def show
@existing_bid = @pin.bid_for(current_user)
end

def new
@pin = current_user.pins.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.'
else
  render action: 'new'
 end
end

def update
if @pin.update(pin_params)
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
else
  render action: 'edit'
 end
end

def destroy
@pin.destroy
redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully destroyed.'
end

private
  def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
 end

def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
     redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this listing." if      @pin.nil?
end

def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image, :image2, :image3, :image4, :image5, :manufacturer, :model)
 end
 end
```

And here is the terms.html.erb

```
<center><h1>Company</h1></center>
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="container-fluid">

<p><h3><b>Terms & Conditions</b></h3>

The terms and conditions will be defined in the listing.

</div>
</div>
```

Rake routes gives:

```
auction GET    /auction(.:format)             pages#auction
terms GET      /terms(.:format)               pages#terms
pins GET       /pins(.:format)                pins#index
new_pin GET    /pins/new(.:format)            pins#new
edit_pin GET   /pins/:id/edit(.:format)       pins#edit
pin GET        /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#show
```

routes.rb

```
get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about_path
get "contact" => "pages#contact" #creates contact_path
get "auction" => "pages#auction" #creates auction_path
get "terms" => "pages#terms" #creates terms_path
post 'send_mail', to: 'contact#send_mail'
get 'contact', to: 'contact#show'
```

How can I resolve this error so people can view the terms and conditions when they are already viewing the pin?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose you have a relative link to the terms like `href="terms"` so clicked in the `/pins/1` it gets to `/pins/terms`, so to fix it you should make it look like `href="/terms"`